# Android slide animation from current position

Tags: android

I am trying to make a slide up-down animation in android. Here is a screenshot and layout file: The blue layout at the bottom disappears and appears by sliding up and down

[image]

slide up xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

and slide down xml file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >


<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

and how i set the animation:

```
relativelayout_slideupdown_bottom.startAnimation(animation_slidedown);
```

The problem is, if i push slide down button first, and then immediately press slide up button, slide up starts from the bottom of screen, not from where the layout was when slide up was pressed, that is natural because i set slide up translation from Y delta 100% to Y delta 0%. It looks like i need to define animation in java code, not in xml file. So the question is, how can i get the current Y position, and when i press slide up before slide down animation ends it starts sliding up from where it was left?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to get what you need is to use [`ValueAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) animations. In the onClick handler of your button, you can just check `isRunning()` on the down animation. If it is running, you simply call **`reverse()`** on the running animation; this will work instantly. If it's not running, you start a new one.

If you need to target Android versions older than API 11, you can use the NineOldAndroids library to get backwards compatibility.